# Get WP Install Directory

Tags: themes, installation, directory, constants

I have a theme which - I was quite proud of myself! - I designed to be installed in wp sites where wp is on root level.

Then half my users installed the theme on a mysite.com**/wordpress/** !

...and it no work...

So some path conversion are in order. I created a number of constants so I didn't always have to rewrite paths. Example:

```
//http constants
$symbiostock_template_directory = get_bloginfo('template_directory');


define('symbiostock_CLASSDIR', $symbiostock_template_directory . '/inc/classes' );
```

...and more constants like this for various paths

```
//filepath constants 
$symbiostock_theme_root = get_theme_root() . '/symbiostock';
define('symbiostock_STOCKDIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/symbiostock_rf/' );
```

...and more constants like this for various paths

define('symbiostock_STOCKDIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/symbiostock_rf/' );

These should work, right?

Is there a nice universal way to get wordpress operating from any level? A "best practice" tutorial out tehre?

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress directory path is available in the constant `ABSPATH`. Be aware this is not related to the `wp-content` directory. The constant `WP_CONTENT_DIR` could be set to exactly the same value. Or another directory on the same level where `WP_CONTENT_URL` is another domain name.

There doesn't even have to be a `wp-content` equivalent: themes, plugins, languages and so on might be spread over different directories.

Do not rely on default paths.

```
define('symbiostock_STOCKDIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/symbiostock_rf/' );
```

This will break in many setups. Use `get_template_directory_uri()` instead, and let WordPress figure out where that is.

Another word on constants: avoid them. There might be collisions with other people’s code. They are slow. Use a [helper function to load classes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/89655/73)  instead, and solve all path problem *in that function’s body,* not in the global namespace.

Comment: A BIG thank you on that. Shows also I have a few things to learn :D. Bookmarked! Even the thing on constants...I thought it was a great way to make life easy and consistent! Didn't know there was a price :D.