# Should I use spl_autoload_register() in my plugin?

Tags: php, plugin-development, errors

When I use spl_autoload_register in my plugin, I get:

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message
   'Class wp_atom_server could not be loaded'

    wp-includes\pluggable-deprecated.php on line 182
```

I did some reading and found various fixes.  [One on SO](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89651/problems-with-autoloading-classes-via-sp-autoload-register-maybe-interfering-w) said not to use spl_autoload_register with WordPress.

Is that accurate?

I'm sure I can find a "fix" for the error, but I'm not sure I want to do that with each WP release.

If I do not use the autoload function, how should I be loading my classes?  Here is what breaks now:

```
spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
spl_autoload_register();

use MyPluginClasses\Student as MS;

$student = new MS\Student();

echo $student->sayHello();
```

In student:

```
<?PHP
namespace MyPluginClasses\Student
{
    class Student{
        public function __Construct(){
            echo "Hello Johnny";
        }
        public function sayHello(){
            echo "Hello Johnny's Method";

        }

    }
}
```

This design works fine outside of WordPress.

Comment: I have updated [my answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/89655/73). If you do it right – with a callback function – you can use `spl_autoload_register()` without negative side-effects.

Comment: @toscho Is your code still the best way to do autoloading in WP?

Comment: No, it is not. The fastest way is to `glob()` the directory once, then deliver the classes when they are needed per `spl_autoload_register()`.

Comment: I will write an answer later, showing our current (not yet published) solution from Multilingual Press.

Answer (score 1):

I am really not sure if it's good or bad practice to auto loading classes in WP plugin. For me, i see no side effects of using `spl_autoload_register` (not tested performance)

So to answer your question, I would like to share a class from my upcoming plugin which i am using to auto load classes from a single directory without any issues and it does well for me so far.

```
/**
 * Annframe Class Autoloader.
 *
 * @package Annframe
 * @since 0.1.0
 */
class Annframe_Autoloader {
    /**
     * Singleton.
     *
     * @since 0.1.0
     * @var Annframe_Autoloader - Single instance.
     */
    private static $_instance = null;

    /**
     * Private Construct.
     *
     * @package Annframe
     * @since 0.1.0
     */
    private function __construct() {
        spl_autoload_register( array( $this, 'load' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Singleton method.
     *
     * @package Annframe
     * @since 0.1.0
     */
    public static function _instance() {
        if ( ! self::$_instance ) {
            self::$_instance = new Annframe_Autoloader();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    /**
     * Class Loader.
     *
     * @package Annframe
     * @since 0.1.0
     *
     * @param string $class_name - Class name to load.
     * @return null - Do not return anything.
     */
    public function load( $class_name ) {
        $file = str_replace( '_', '-', strtolower( $class_name ) );
        $file = 'class-' . $file;
        if ( is_readable( trailingslashit( YOUR_PLUGIN_PATH. '/classes-dir' ) . $file . '.php' ) ) {
            include_once trailingslashit( YOUR_PLUGIN_PATH. '/classes-dir' ) . $file . '.php';
        }
        return;
    }
}

Annframe_Autoloader::_instance();
```

To break this simple class in parts as you see i am using Singleton pattern. `Constructor` is private and `instance()` & `$_instance` belongs to the pattern. Constructor has `spl_autoload_register` function.

```
spl_autoload_register( array( $this, 'load' ) );
```

which is calling `load` method from self class. 
The first two lines from this method is:

```
$file = str_replace( '_', '-', strtolower( $class_name ) );
$file = 'class-' . $file;
```

which is pretty straight. if you follow **WPCS** it encourages you to follow a class naming convention prefixed with word **class** and then class name. ofcourse any underscore (_) is replaced with (-) dash.

so a file name of class `WPSE_Post` would be `class-wpse-post.php`

Lower casing class names with `strtolower` and using `str_replace` to replace underscores with dashes. so `WPSE_Post` now becomes `wpse-post`. finally adding a prefix `class-` on next line.

i am using `is_readable` in conditional statement which is exchangeable with `file_exists`. assuming `YOUR_PLUGIN_PATH` is plugin's base path and `classes-dir` is under main plugin dir holding all of your classes that needs autoloading .

`include_once` is used to load the actual file on call.

**Usage:**

you just need to include the above auto loader class in your plugin's base file

```
/**
 * Class autoloader.
 */
if ( ! class_exists( 'Annframe_Autoloader' ) ) {
    include_once YOUR_PLUGIN_PATH/class-annframe-autoloader.php';
}
```

and then call your classes on demand.

```
new XYX_Class();
Another_Class::instance(); // etc
```

**Note:** I am not using namespace method in my solution so it may or may not fit according to your needs but posted here in hope that someone atleast get benefits of loading classes dynamically.

Comment: Do you have an example but with namespace?

Answer (score -1):

```
    function MyPluginClasses_autoloader( $class_name ) {
  if ( false !== strpos( $class_name, 'MyPluginClasses' ) ) {
    $parts = explode('\\', $class_name);
    require_once RoothPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'lib'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.end($parts) . '.php';
  }
}
spl_autoload_register( 'MyPluginClasses_autoloader' );
use MyPluginClasses\Student as MS;
$student = new MS\Student();
echo $student->sayHello();
```

Comment: Although posting code is good you should explain how and why this answer the question.

Comment: as your plugin is not the only plugin in the system, code that just loads classes without verifying first that they are yours, is going to create trouble sooner or later by trying to load the wrong file for a class declared in another plugin.